# How to combine two objects in a List by summing a member

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given this `case class`:

```
case class Categories(fruit: String, amount: Double, mappedTo: String)
```

I have a list containing the following:

```
List(
  Categories("Others",22.38394964594807,"Others"),
  Categories("Others",77.6160503540519,"Others")
)
```

I want to combine two elements in the list by summing up their amount if they are in the same category, so that the end result in this case would be:

```
List(Categories("Others",99.99999999999997,"Others"))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look at using `groupBy` or `groupMapReduce` to collect all the "similar" values and then merge the appropriate fields.

Comment: How do you want to do that? Based on Fruit? mappedTo? Both?

Comment: I want to group by only mappedTo only

Comment: And what should be the fruit in case there are 2 different ones with the same mappedTo?

Comment: As of now in the given data, we don't consider to group based on fruit, we only need to group by only mappedTo, think about mappedTo and fruit have same data

Comment: Mohd, please take the [tour], and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You want to group your list entries by category, and reduce them to a single value. There is `groupMapReduce` for that, which groups entries, and then maps the group (you don't need this) and reduces the group to a single value.

given

`case class Category(category: String, amount: Double)`

if you have a `val myList: List[Category]`, then you want to *group* on `Category#category`, and reduce them by merging the members, summing up the amount.

that gives

```
myList.groupMapReduce(_.category) //group
                     (identity)   //map. We don't need to map, so we use the identity mapping
                     {
                        case (Category(name, amount1), Category(_, amount2)) =>
                          Category(name, amount1 + amount2) }
                     }            //reduce, combine each elements by taking the name, and summing the amojunts
```

In theory just a `groupReduce` would have been enough, but that doesn't exist, so we're stuck with the identity here.

Answer (score 3):

Since [groupMapReduce](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/72cd6f4bdb72f55ccda618966a3e4b7051cc5885) was introduced in Scala 2.13, I'll try to provide another approch to [Martinjn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64551722/2359227)'s great answer.

Assuming we have:

```
case class Categories(Fruit: String, amount: Double, mappedTo: String)
val categories = List(
  Categories("Apple",22.38394964594807,"Others"),
  Categories("Apple",77.6160503540519,"Others")
)
```

If you want to aggregate by both `mappedTo` and `Fruit`

```
val result = categories.groupBy(c => (c.Fruit, c.mappedTo)).map {
  case ((fruit, mappedTo), categories) => Categories(fruit, categories.map(_.amount).sum, mappedTo)
}
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rfTJjxI1Q0OW9TjlZJPdtg).

If you want to aggregate only by `mappedTo`, and choose a random `Fruit`, you can do:

```
val result = categories.groupBy(c => c.mappedTo).map {
  case (mappedTo, categories) => Categories(categories.head.Fruit, categories.map(_.amount).sum, mappedTo)
}
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vbARkHobQ9eCNwipbGLEZQ)